# window.frames["frame_name"] doesn't work in Firefox when frame has been removed and readded

Tags: firefox, frame

1. Add a frame to the page
2. Remove it
3. Add another frame with the same name
4. `window.frames["frame_name"]` doesn't work

#### HTML

```html
<iframe id="replaceme" name="frame_1"></iframe><br />
```

#### JS

```js
$("body").append(window.frames[0].name + "<br />");
$("body").append(window.frames["frame_1"].name + "<br />");
$("body").append( (window.frames[0] == window.frames["frame_1"]) + "<br />");

$("#replaceme").remove();

$("body").append('<iframe name="frame_1"></iframe><br />');

$("body").append(window.frames[0].name + "<br />");
$("body").append(window.frames["frame_1"].name + "<br />");
$("body").append( (window.frames[0] == window.frames["frame_1"]) + "<br />");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xbmSs/

Is this a bug or expected behavior? It works fine in Opera, Safari, Chrome. Any suggestions of how to work around it in Firefox?

Comment: Your example seems to be working in Chrome.

Comment: OK, looks like it has been a bug [since 2002](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=170799). Still looking for Firefox workaround.

Comment: Seems like the only workaround is to not reuse frame names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug, as you already figured out.

There are two options for workarounds, in addition to not reusing frame names:

1)  You could `delete window.frames["frame_name"]` either when removing the relevant frame from the DOM or right before you access `window.frames["frame_name"]`.  Either one should work in Firefox, but I can't speak to other browsers.

2)  You could switch to using `document.getElementById("frame_id").contentWindow`.  The big problem there is IE compat, especially in older IE versions...

Comment: Note that the `delete window.frames["frame_name"]` method throws an "Object doesn't support this action" in IE8